# Get specific JSON from database table with php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization

Here I have this datatable:

[image]

I want to get data for id_akt=22. Now first I group datum for id_akt:

```
SELECT datum FROM `track_aktivnosti` WHERE id_akt=22 GROUP BY `datum` ORDER BY `datum` ASC
```

and I get this:

```
datum  
2013-04-01
2013-09-08
2014-06-25
```

1. Now I want to create part of json for cols:
   so to be like this:

   {"cols":[{"label":"datum","type":"date"},{"label":"djubrivo b432","type":"string"},{"label":"nema nema","type":"string"},{"label":"Laza Lazic","type":"string"},{"label":"dbdbd","type":"string"},{"label":"John Deer n7","type":"string"},{"label":"Mika Mikic","type":"string"},{"label":"Pera Peric","type":"string"}]

its easy and I do this with:

```
SELECT naziv FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = 22 AND prvi=1
```

2. After that I need to get rows for each datum above I get (3 dates) to be a part of JSON so `vrednost` for each naziv WHERE id-akt=22 and datum[0] 
   so JSON will loos like this;

   "rows":[{"c":[{"v":0},{"v":"0"},{"v":"0"},{"v":"U 0"},{"v":"0"},{"v":"0"},

now I must get datum[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV2hE.jpg) and create new `"c"` for my JSON

**QUERY WILL LOOKS LIKE ???**

i need to be like this becouse I need to use it in google visualisation datatable, but how to o this?

Comment: You will typically want to write some code to reformat your data in the format Google needs.  Don't write a query for your output format.  Write a query to get the data, then format it as needed at the application layer.

Comment: thats not posibble becouse google need json format like i put above

Comment: It is possible... I do it all the time.  You make a query from your database to get the data you need, then build an object in the format Google needs (which can be done with a simple `foreach` loop, adding stdClass instances to an array), then you `json_encode()` and `echo()` the whole thing.